# Executing a JavaScript file directly from the browser

Tags: javascript, browser

This sounds like a trivia question but I really need to know.

If you put the URL of an HTML file in the Location bar of your browser, it will render that HTML.  That's the whole purpose of a browser.

If you give it a JPG, or a SWF, or even PDF, it will do the right things for those datatypes.

But, if you give it the URL of a JavaScript file, it will *display* the text of that file.  What I want is for that file to be executed directly.

Now, I know that if you use the `javascript:` protocol, it will execute the *text* of the URL, but that isn't what I need.

I could have the URL point to an HTML file consisting of a single `<script>` tag that in turn points to the JavaScript file, but for occult reasons of my own, I cannot do that.

If the file at `http://example.com/file.js` consists entirely of

```
 alert("it ran");
```

And I put that URL in the Location bar, I want "it ran" to pop up as an alert.

I'm skeptical that this is possible but I'm hoping-against-hope that there is a header or a MIME type or something like that that I can set and miraculously make this happen.

Comment: the problem is: in which context will this script be executed? Should the browser create an empty HTML page?

Comment: Pretty sure this is not possible for the reason that levu described

Comment: @Smamatti — `x-`? It stopped being experimental [in 2006](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4329.txt). That won't work though.

Comment: Not an unreasonable question.  A dev might want to make something in JS and not immediately lose it like they would if they typed it in dev tool's console.  But Domenic's answer below makes sense.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is not possible. The browser has no idea what context the JavaScript should run in; for example, what are the properties of `window`? If you assume it can come up with some random defaults, what about the behavior of `document`? If someone does `document.body.innerHTML = "foo"` what should happen?

JavaScript, unlike images or HTML pages, is dependent on a context in which it runs. That context could be a HTML page, or it could be a Node server environment, or it could even be Windows Scripting Host. But if you just navigate to a URL, the browser has no idea what context it should run the script in.

---

As a workaround, perhaps use `about:blank` as a host page. Then you can insert the script into the document, giving it the appropriate execution context, by pasting the following in your URL bar:

```
javascript:(function () { var el = document.createElement("script"); el.src = "PUT_URL_HERE"; document.body.appendChild(el); })();
```

Comment: The problem of context never occurred to me.  The context I want is the same that would be provided to a completely blank HTML page -- but there is obviously a huge gap between what *I* know and what the browser knows.

Comment: coding makes you humble @Malvolio :)

Answer (score 3):

Or you can use RunJS: https://github.com/Dharmoslap/RunJS

Then you will be able to run .js files just with drag&drop.

Answer (score 2):

Not directly, but you could make a simple server-side script, e.g. in PHP. Instead of

```
http://example.com/file.js
```

, navigate to:

```
http://localhost/execute_script.php?url=http://example.com/file.js
```

Of course, you could smallen this by using `RewriteRule` in Apache, and/or adding another entry in your hosts file that redirects to `127.0.0.1`.

Note that this is not great in terms of security, but if you use it yourself and know what you're downloading, you should be fine.

```
<html>
 <head>

  <script>
   <? echo file_get_contents($_GET['url']); ?>
  </script>

 </head>

 <body>

 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the address bar, you simply write

javascript:/*some javascript code here*/;void(0);

http://www.javascriptkata.com/2007/05/01/execute-javascript-code-directly-in-your-browser/

Comment: Doesn't work for me in 2023 in Firefox

Answer (score 0):

Use Node.js. 
Download and install node.js and create a http/s server and write down what you want to display in browser. 
use localhost::portNumber on server as url to run your file. 
refer to node js doc - https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v7.x/docs/api/http.html

Run - http://localhost:3000

sample code below :

```
  var http = require("http");
  var server = http.createServer(function(req,res){
  res.writeHead(200,{'Content-Type':'text/html'});
       res.end("hello user");
  }); server.listen(3000);`
```

Answer (score -2):

you can write your own browser using qt /webkit and do that.
when user enters a js file in url location you can read that file and execute the javascript .

http://code.google.com/apis/v8/get_started.html is another channel.
not sure if it meets ur need.

Comment: No, thanks.  I have control over the script and the server, but not the browser.