# Respond with JavaScript in Rack app

Tags: javascript, ruby, web, rack

I have a Rack app where I need to respond with JavaScript. I am trying set content type as JavaScript, while sending the response but its not working, it seems like I am missing somthing.

The simple response I am sending is:

```
require 'rubygems'   
require 'rack'  
run Proc.new { |env| ['200', {'Content-Type' => 'application/javascript'},["alert('hi')"]]}
```

Can a Rack app respond with a JavaScript content-type? Or could it be the browser is not executing the received JavaScript?

Comment: Have you looked at the network traffic in your Firebug or Chrome Tools?

Comment: can you please show the rest of the middleware? the response looks ok

Comment: Can you post the JS that is receiving this response?

Comment: @yoavmatchulsky Its an simple 2 line code run Proc.new { |env| ['200', {'Content-Type' => 'application/javascript'},["alert('hi')"]],In browser it is rendering as text instead of executing javascript.

Comment: @diego.greyrobot alert('hi') rendering to browser as HTML/text instead of executing the javascript

Comment: I think this is relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7717382/executing-a-javascript-file-directly-from-the-browser. What you’re doing is okay in terms of setting the content-type, but the browser won’t execute js code downloaded directly like this.

Answer (score 0):

as @matt said above, and what I was trying to figure out is that you can't just give the browser js and expect it to run. It has to be executed by an ajax callback. Take jQuery for example:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/path/to/your/js",
  dataType: "script"
});
```

That `dataType` property tells jQuery to execute the script that is returned by the server. The point being that you need javascript to execute javascript, simply navigating to a URL won't do it.